# Replacing two positive integers with sum of them until getting a single number and concluding the nature of final number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

Assume that there are $n$ number of positive integers written on a paper. And the difference of any pair of those numbers is not divisible by $n$.

We erase two numbers and write the sum of them. If we repeat this until we get a single number, can we conclude the following statements?

1. If $n$ is Odd, The final number we will get will be divisible by $n$.
2. If $n$ is Even, After dividing The final number by $n$ the remainder will be $n/2$.
3. There is a $n$ value that makes the final number less than ${n(n+1)}/2$.

Comment: The hypothesis tells us that the numbers are all different modulo $n$

Comment: @vadim123 What's the mean of "different modulo n"? Can you explain it simply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Different modulo n", by definition means that the difference of no two of them is divisible by n. Equivalently, we can say that each one of them leaves a different remainder on division by $n$.

The hypothesis thus implies that the numbers are $$x_{1}\equiv0,x_{2}\equiv1,x_{3}\equiv2,...,x_{n}\equiv n-1 \mod n$$
(we "replace" each one of them by its remainder on division by $n$).  Consequently, their sum reads:
$$x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+...+x_{n}\equiv \frac{(n-1)n}{2} \mod n$$
Thus:

- If $n$ is odd, $n-1$ is even and thus $\frac{(n-1)n}{2}$ is divisible by $n$
- If $n$ is even, $\frac{(n-1)n}{2}=\frac{(n-2)n}{2}+\frac{n}{2}\equiv\frac{n}{2}\mod n$, because $\frac{(n-2)n}{2}$ is divisible by $n$, since $n-2$ is even
- Regarding the third statement, I do not think it is true: since the initial numbers are only specified $\mod n$, their sum is unbounded.

Comment: The answer seems like great. But I can't understand this part,
$x_1≡0,x_2≡1,x_3≡2,...,x_n≡ n−1 mod n$

Comment: The possible remaiders on division by $n$, are the $n$ integers $$0\leq r\leq n-1$$ So if we have $n$ numbers, such that, each one of them leaves a different remainder on division by $n$, the only possibility is that $$x_{1}\equiv0,x_{2}\equiv1,x_{3}\equiv2,...,x_{n}\equiv n-1 \mod n$$ (with a suitable rearrangement of the numbers)